# Convergence of sequence of a function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose that $f$ is a function defined on an interval $I$ and $c$ is an element of $I$.  If $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence in $I$ that converges to $c$, and if the sequence $(f(x_n))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $L$, may we conclude that the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $c$ is equal to $L$? Explain.

Comment: You might try playing with the function $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$ for $x\ne0$, $f(0)=0$, and $c=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Some people take this as the definition of a limit of a function:

$$f(x) \to L \text{ as } x \to l,$$
if and only if 
$$f(x_n) \to L \text{ as } n \to \infty$$
for all sequences $x_n$ such that $x_n \to l$ with $x_n \neq l$ for all $.$

(see eg my book Proof Patterns)

However, it has to be ALL sequences. If it is just one sequence it doesn't work. Eg take 
$f(x) =1$ for $x \geq 0$ and $-1$ for $x \leq 0.$ Then a positive sequence of $x_n$ going to zero gives $1$ and a negative one gives $-1.$